# Building an APK with Buildozer and Kivy on OSX - Cython for Python3 Missing

Tags: macos, kivy, apk, cython, buildozer

I am trying to build an app, written in kivy and python 3.7, using buildozer but I keep running into a particular error, around cython for python3 missing, which causes the build to fail.

Thanks to some of the kind help I have received on this forum so far, I have managed to eliminate most of the previous errors I found. I am using:

- Buildozer 0.40.dev0
- Python-for-android 2019.08.09.1.dev0
- Android NDK r20

The only error that is being generated at the moment, which causes the build to fail, comes from an earlier warning:

`[WARNING]: Cython for python3 missing. If you are building for  a python 3 target (which is the default) then THINGS WILL BREAK.`

Looking at the error code where the build breaks, this is what appears:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'Cython.Build.Cythonize' (ImportError: No module named 'Cython')`

I've put the full transcript here:

https://apilotslens.com/buildozer-errors-after-first-build-failed

I don't understand at all why it isn't working. Please could you take a look at the transcript, to try to identify the issue and how to correct it?

It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Cython for python 3.7 is installed. I used `pip3.7 install cython` for that and it is the most up-to-date version: `0.29.13`. The only thing I can think of is that it is something to do with the `python.framework` folder, shown earlier, where the error output is. How do I solve this error?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know about Bulldozer or Python for Android but : Your error reports `Versions/3.5`; you say you've installed Cython for python 3. __7__. Might this be the problem?

Comment: Well I thought that might be the case. I didn't understand why 3.5 was there anyway. However, after installing cython with Conda, the error now no longer appears. It gets most of the way through the build and then fails. This is the latest error: apilotslens.com/buildozer-error-missing-name-key-attribute-sdk . Do you know what this might mean or what the issue is?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know much about Bulldozer. Sorry

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pip3 :

```
 pip3 install Cython
```